# Adsense is firing blanks - Is there a test I can check against?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have been asked to drop in an adsense snippet for a clients site. the iFrame appears to be loading, but no content is visible.

How can I test that everything is okay? The site is currently localhost only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adsense sometimes just does this for a while when it is getting started.  I'd give it a few hours and see if it starts working on its own.

Comment: I mean, once you put the code on the page, it hasn't always worked for me right away.

Comment: As long as you are seeing an iframe loaded from somewhere google-ish or doubleclick-ish, you're probably fine, even though it's blank.